# reading analog not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, spi, analog-to-digital

I have a Raspberry Pi3, and I am following this tutorial:
http://raspberrypi-aa.github.io/session3/spi.html

The code I am using is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Bitbang'd SPI interface with an MCP3008 ADC device
# MCP3008 is 8-channel 10-bit analog to digital converter
#  Connections are:
#     CLK => 18  
#     DOUT => 23 (chip's data out, RPi's MISO)
#     DIN => 24  (chip's data in, RPi's MOSI)
#     CS => 25 

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys

CLK = 18
MISO = 23
MOSI = 24
CS = 25

def setupSpiPins(clkPin, misoPin, mosiPin, csPin):
    ''' Set all pins as an output except MISO (Master Input, Slave Output)'''
    GPIO.setup(clkPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(misoPin, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(mosiPin, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(csPin, GPIO.OUT)
     

def readAdc(channel, clkPin, misoPin, mosiPin, csPin):
    if (channel < 0) or (channel > 7):
        print "Invalid ADC Channel number, must be between [0,7]"
        return -1
        
    # Datasheet says chip select must be pulled high between conversions
    GPIO.output(csPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    
    # Start the read with both clock and chip select low
    GPIO.output(csPin, GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(clkPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    
    # read command is:
    # start bit = 1
    # single-ended comparison = 1 (vs. pseudo-differential)
    # channel num bit 2
    # channel num bit 1
    # channel num bit 0 (LSB)
    read_command = 0x18
    read_command |= channel
    
    sendBits(read_command, 5, clkPin, mosiPin)
    
    adcValue = recvBits(12, clkPin, misoPin)
    
    # Set chip select high to end the read
    GPIO.output(csPin, GPIO.HIGH)
  
    return adcValue
    
def sendBits(data, numBits, clkPin, mosiPin):
    ''' Sends 1 Byte or less of data'''
    
    data <<= (8 - numBits)
    
    for bit in range(numBits):
        # Set RPi's output bit high or low depending on highest bit of data field
        if data & 0x80:
            GPIO.output(mosiPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
            GPIO.output(mosiPin, GPIO.LOW)
        
        # Advance data to the next bit
        data <<= 1
        
        # Pulse the clock pin HIGH then immediately low
        GPIO.output(clkPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(clkPin, GPIO.LOW)

def recvBits(numBits, clkPin, misoPin):
    '''Receives arbitrary number of bits'''
    retVal = 0
    
    for bit in range(numBits):
        # Pulse clock pin 
        GPIO.output(clkPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(clkPin, GPIO.LOW)
        
        # Read 1 data bit in
        if GPIO.input(misoPin):
            retVal |= 0x1
        
        # Advance input to next bit
        retVal <<= 1
    
    # Divide by two to drop the NULL bit
    return (retVal/2)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        setupSpiPins(CLK, MISO, MOSI, CS)
    
        while True:
            val = readAdc(0, CLK, MISO, MOSI, CS)
            print "ADC Result: ", str(val)
            time.sleep(5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
sys.exit(0)
```

The program output is persistently "ADC result 0"
I have an exact copy of the analog circuit, and I am using the MCP3008 ADC converter. I have tried installing python-dev, and I have the spi module according to this command:

```
$sudo lsmod | grep spi
spi_bcm2835
```

SPI is enabled according to the raspberry pi con fig. I have checked all the connections, and read all the available help on this page.

I have run an SPI debugger linking MISO and MOSI and as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#spi-overview) and got this output:

```
./spidev_test -D /dev/spidev0.0
spi mode: 0
bits per word: 8
max speed: 500000 Hz (500 KHz)

FF FF FF FF FF FF
40 00 00 00 00 95
FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF FF FF FF FF FF
DE AD BE EF BA AD
F0 0D
```

What can I do to debug SPI? Why isn't this thing working?

Comment: We are going to need to see pics of your circuit and the code you are using. Note: add these to your question directly not as links to third party services.

Comment: ok I will update soon

Comment: There is no need to bit bang.  Change your code to use the Python spidev module.

Comment: I do not read frizzy, a schematic would be a big help. Post a schematic exactly how you have it wired including power, ground and power. Do not forget to post links to the hardware devices that show technical info. Links to azon and other similar sales outlets do not normally contain the needed technical data.